# Proving that $|\langle x,y\rangle|=\|x\|\|y\|$ iff $x,y$ are linearly dependent

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

**Show**: For any vectors $x$ and $y$ in an inner product space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, we have $$\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|=\|x\|\|y\| \iff x,y \ are \ dependent$$

---

($\leftarrow$) If $x$ and $y$ are dependent, then $x=ky$, $k\in \mathbb{F}$. So, $$|\langle x,y\rangle|=|\langle kx,y\rangle|=|k|\|y\|^2=|k|\|y\|\|y\|=\|ky\|\|y\|=\|x\|\|y\| $$

How, do I prove ($\rightarrow$)?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: See [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @WalterWhite So how could we prove equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies linear dependence?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $y \neq 0$, otherwise there's not much to show. If $y \neq 0$, let $x_{//} = \frac{\langle x, y\rangle}{\langle y, y\rangle} y$ and $x_{\perp} = x - x_{//}$. Show that $\langle x, y\rangle = \langle x_{//}, y \rangle$ and $\| x_{//}\| \leq \| x \|$ with equality if and only if $x = x_{//}$. Therefore, $| \langle x, y \rangle| = |\langle x_{//}, y \rangle| \leq \|x_{//}\| \|y\|$, but by assumption $|\langle x, y\rangle| = \|x\|\|y\|$ which will imply that $\|x\|=\|x_{//}\|$ and hence $x = x_{//}$. Now, you have that $x_{//}$ is linearly dependent on $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the assertion holds trivially when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Let $c\in \mathbb R$ such that $\|y\|=c\|x\|$. Then
$$
\|cx-y\|^2=\langle cx-y,cx-y\rangle=\|cx\|^2+\|y\|^2-2c \langle x,y\rangle\\=\|cx\|^2+\|y\|^2-2c\|x\|\,\|y\|=\|cx\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\|cx\|\,\|y\|\\=(\|cx\|-\|y\|)^2=(c\|x\|-\|y\|)^2=0.
$$
So $\|cx-y\|=0$, and this means that $y=cx$.

Answer (score 0):

In case $x\neq0$, show that the length of the vector $y-\dfrac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|^2}x$ equals zero.

Comment: what if $x = -y \neq 0$?

Comment: Then $x$ and $y$ are linear dependent.  I don't get what you are pointing at.

Comment: If $x = -y$, then $y- \frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}x = 2y$, so the length needn't be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've corrected it.